# Is it necessary to define on a FOREIGN KEY the same constraints that are defined on the PRIMARY KEY (parent table)?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I create a table `Clients`. I define a primary key and a set of constraints, such as:

- NOT NULL
- Length > 5
- UPPERCASE

and so on..

Now, I create another table, with a foreign key to `Clients` primary key.
Should I create the same CONSTRAINTS for the foreign key?

If I don't it wouldn't matter, since the value won't exist on the primary table in the first place:

Example: I don't create the constraints on the foreign key, and I try to add a value which length is lower than 5 characters, and is lowercase... The database will not find that value on the parent table, hence the value will not be recorded, so what is the point of setting the same set of constraints on the foreign table?

Comment: That would be a badly chosen primary key and foreign key. Primary keys and foreign keys should not be user entered data they should be a unique automatically generated key.

Comment: But even if you did choose to use 'user entered data' as your primary key, the point of a foreign key is that it exactly matches a primary key. So unless you enforce that somehow your system isn't going to work.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I agree that PRIMARY KEYS should be generated by the system, with INTEGRITY, but is that the case for a FOREIGN KEY ?

Let's say I create a table CLIENTS. Each client has it's own unique client id, generated by the system, that's ok. 

Now, let's say there is another table called Transactions. Each transaction will have it's own transaction id, that will be generated by the system, and that is ok. BUT, the client id on the transaction, cannot be auto generated by the system, because the client already exists on the CLIENT table.. client id should be choosen by me, or the systm

Comment: Well yes, the point of a foreign key is to directly, uniquely, reference a primary key in another table.

Answer (score 0):

At least you should keep the Foreign key column as not null. Otherwise, you can have many NULL values coming into the child table.

Again, as @Dale Burrell, mentioned, PRIMARY KEY should be system generated, to enforce uniqueness. If you are going to create clustered index on the primary key column, it should be narrow, incrementing, not null, unique value for getting good performance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the length or uppercase constraints on the foreign key. They'll be "implicitly checked" by the foreign key constraint (as you say, because the referenced data cannot exist).

But for nullability, it's a choice. In SQL Server, if one or more columns in the referencing table of a foreign key are `NULL`, the constraint isn't enforced.

So here, the question should instead be - are there rows in the other table which should validly *not reference* a row in the `Clients` table?

---

Others have advised that the PK should be system generated. Whilst I agree that it's often useful to do so, don't forget to *also* enforce the constraints on the real data. E.g. even if this column doesn't end up being your PK, maybe it needs a unique constraint on it to ensure that you don't end up with duplicates in your data.

Comment: Thanks.
What do you mean by "System Generated" ?
I am a student. The only way we were thought to generate PK is by defining the column as PK... that is, WE define the PK. I don't know what would be a PK generated by the system.

Comment: Damien, sorry, I didn't understand the nullability thing... 

"But for nullability, it's a choice. In SQL Server, if one or more columns in the referencing table of a foreign key are NULL, the constraint isn't enforced.

So here, the question should instead be - are there rows in the other table which should validly not reference a row in the Clients table?"

Can you epxplain in other words ?

Comment: @user2324238 - system generated - that would be to use an `IDENTITY` column in SQL Server or a `SEQUENCE`. nullability - imagine that the PK in Clients is `ClientID`. If the FK to clients is also called `ClientID`, it either a) contains a non-null value that must match a PK value in clients or b) it can be null. In the second case, we *don't* seek a PK value in clients which is null. There's no reference.